# How to pass data Between vue single file component

Tags: vue.js

I have (my first) app in vue that get data from api and render some select elements.
I want to separe each box to another file (one file for get data from api, second for render select, third for render list).
How can i pass data from

I tried to get data from instance of api:

```
  export default {
      props: {
          filters: apiIntance.$data.kpis.filters,
```

For this moment i have something like that:

```
<!-- src/components/Filters.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="filters">
      <label v-bind:key="filter.id" v-for="filter in filters">
          <select class="js-selectbox">
              <option v-bind:value="item.id" v-bind:key="item.id" v-for="item in filter.items">{{item.name}}</option>
          </select>
      </label>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';

    import Api from './ApiTest.vue';

    export default {
        props: {
            filters: //Get Data from ApiTest.vue
        },
    };
</script>
```

```
<!-- src/components/ApiTest.vue -->
export default Vue.extend({
data(): DataObject {
    return {
        kpis: {
            ...
        },
    };
  },
```

Have you some tips how to get data in one file and spread it for other files?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your issue? vue is datadriven - so you create components in respect to the data it should handle - and pass down via props, and emit upwards via events?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) which is a vue data management plugin that all your components will have access to

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vue'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // data will be stored here
  state: {
    apiData: null,
  },
  mutations: {
   // you call this mutation to add data  
    apiData(state) {
      state.apiData = apiData
    }
  },
  getters: {
    // a getter for the data
    apiData(state) {
      retrun state.apiData
    }
  }
})

// new Vue({...,store})
```

you can add data to the store immediately after the fetching with :

```js
this.$store.commit('apiData',yourdatahere)
```

and then access/get it on any component with :

```js
this.$store.getters.apiData
```

you can read more about [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways, to name a few

1. `one file for get data from api` don't need to be a vue instance. You may want to add more hooks.

```
// ApiService.ts
export const ApiService = { getData: () => {/**/} }

// src/components/Filters.vue
...
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import {ApiService} from '@/.../ApiService'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      filters: []
    }),
    created() {
      ApiService.getData().then(data => this.filters = data)
    }
  };
</script>
```

2. You can certainly make a Vue instance to provide data, to make it reactive and component independent from data logic. For example:

```
// ApiService.ts
const ApiService = new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    filters: []
  }),
  created() {
    request().then(data => this.filters = data)
  }
})

// src/components/Filters.vue
...
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import {ApiService} from '@/.../ApiService'

  export default {
    computed: {
        filters() {
          return ApiService.filters
        }
    }

  };
</script>
```

Comment: Bottom line: it's kind of weird to use SFC for a data service. Use `.ts` instead